# How to update ModelState?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a controller action that I call with ajax post method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Comment comment)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            comment.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            comment.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.db.Add(comment);
            return PartialView("Comment", comment);
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

If the user is logged in, submit form doesn't have Username and Email fields, so they don't get passed by ajax call. When action gets called ModelStat.IsValid returns false, because these two properties are required. After I set valid values to properties, how do I trigger model validation to update ModelState?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom [model binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.aspx) to bind the comment's Username and Email properties from User.Identity. Because binding occurs before validation the ModelState will be valid then.

Another option is to implement a custom [model validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidator.aspx) for the Comment class, that checks the [ControllerContext.Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidator.controllercontext.aspx) for a validated user.

By implementing any of these options you can remove the first if check.

Comment: I was afraid that it will come to that. Any other solution?

Comment: Don't be afraid, those are the cleanest, the "most MVC" solutions. By applying them you will also learn a bit more about the framework you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just hopping to keep it simple. I've implemented custom model binder, that way I kept validation. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: any chance someone could post an example of how you would use the model binder in OP's case?

Answer (score 4):

You can try calling the built in [TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx) method which returns a boolean so you can check that value.

**UPDATE:  Try using TryUpdateModel with exceptions. Use a formcollection instead of Comment into the Action.**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(FormCollection collection)
    {

        string[] excludedProperties = new string[] { "Username". "Email" };
        var comment = new Comment();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            comment.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            comment.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email;
        }

        TryUpdateModel<Comment>(comment, "", null, excludedProperties, collection.ToValueProvider());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.db.Add(comment);
            return PartialView("Comment", comment);
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, that's first thing I tried and all other method in a controller: UpdateModel, ValidateModel, TryValidate. None of that works, I get an exception: Model can't be updated/validated or somthing similar.

Comment: In that case why not use a ViewModel? This will encompass all the properties you do pass to the Action and no need to worry about the missing ones.

Comment: I think its not a good idea to use a viewmodel with something that will be server added like a user from the the membership